# java String-based on reverse

Tags: java, string

How to reverse whole paragraph in input_1 except words in input_2?
 The output should be like this....

```
 String input_1="this is me.is this is me";
 String input_2="is,me";

 String output="me is siht is.me is siht";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Users here generally prefer to answer questions that show what the author has already tried :)

Comment: Show us something you got!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vague as your question is as to input expression syntax, I will answer it assuming that you enter the second string  (String input_2 as in your code snippet) as a list of all words which are not to be reversed, separated by commas. This is the working code solution to your question as I understood it.
Kindly forgive my indentation and formatting as I wrote it on VIM in a jiffy.

```
import java.io.*;
public class SelectReverse
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the string to be selectively reversed");
    String str = buf.readLine(); 
    str = str.trim();
    str = " ".concat(str);
    int len = str.length();    //length of first input string
    System.out.println("Enter the words to be left intact during reversal");
    String s = buf.readLine();
    int l = s.length();     //length of second input string
    int j = 0;
    int k = len-1;         //stores index upto which substring is extracted
    int wordcount = 1;
    String result = "";    //stores output string
    for(int i = 0; i<l; i++)        //counts no. of words which are not to be reversed
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == ',')                                          
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
    }
    String arr[] = new String[wordcount];   //array of words not to be reversed
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<l; i++)                                        
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == ',')
        {
            String subs = s.substring(j, i); //extracting individual words from list of words not to be reversed
            arr[counter] = subs;    //adding them in the array
            j = i+1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    arr[counter] = s.substring(j);  //adding last word (after the last comma)
    boolean firstflag = false;
    for(int i = len-1; i>=0; i--)
    {        
        String substr;
        if(str.charAt(i)==' ' || str.charAt(i)=='.')
        {
            if(firstflag == false)  //substring is extracted till end of string only for the first extracted word
            {
                substr = str.substring(i+1);
                firstflag = true;
                k = i;
            }
            else
            {
                substr = str.substring(i+1, k);
                k = i;
            }        
            boolean flag = false;
            for(int m = 0; m<wordcount; m++)
            {
                if(arr[m].equalsIgnoreCase(substr))//true if substring is not to be reversed, i.e. matches with any word in array
                {                
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if(flag == true) //concatenating substring to output string without reversing
            {
                result = result+substr;
                result = result+" ";
            }
            else   //concatenating substring to output string after reversing
            {
                String reverse = "";
                int ln = substr.length();
                for(int n = ln-1; n>=0; n--)    //reversing substring
                {
                    char ch = substr.charAt(n);
                    String chstring = Character.toString(ch);
                    reverse = reverse+chstring;
                }
                result = result+reverse;
                result = result+" ";
            }        
        }
    }    
    System.out.println(result); //displaying resultant output string
  } 
}
```

This should solve your problem. For further questions please be more specific about input syntax, regex and problem statement.
You can also use the .split(String, delimiter) method to create an array of substrings in the String separated by the delimiter, but I have shown the implementation of the method for clarity and basic level understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use following example for reference:-

```
public class ReverseWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input1 = "this is me.is this is me";
        String input2 = "is,me";
        String output = "";

        String[] wordsFromInput1 = input1.split("[\\s.]");
        String[] wordsFromInput2 = input2.split(",");

        for (String tempWord1 : wordsFromInput1) {
            boolean existInSecond = false;
            for (String tempWord2 : wordsFromInput2) {
                if (tempWord1.equals(tempWord2)) {
                    existInSecond = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (existInSecond) {
                output += tempWord1 + " ";
            } else {
                output += new StringBuffer(tempWord1).reverse() + " ";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(output.trim());
    }
}
```

You have to learn more on **regular expression** and **string** processing functions to work on such string processing examples.